# Best way for MultiAutoCompleteTextView with custom adapter that can have id for selected value

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I am trying to implement a MultiAutoCompleteTextView to fetch recipients stored in SQLite.

The table structure for this is Friend ID and Friend Name.

In the main activity, I'm having the following code

```
ArrayList<Friends> myObjs = databaseH.getfriends();


        ArrayAdapterItem adapter = new ArrayAdapterItem(this, R.layout.list_view_row, myObjs);

        mactv = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById (R.id.sendTo);


        mactv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mactv.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
        mactv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String[] toArr = mactv.getText().toString().split(", ");

                for(int i=0;i<toArr.length;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println(toArr[i]);
                }           
            }


        });
```

The custom adapter used here is as follows:

public class ArrayAdapterItem extends ArrayAdapter {

```
Context mContext;
int layoutResourceId;
Friends data[] = null;
private ArrayList<Friends> catList;
public ArrayAdapterItem(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Friends> catList) {

    super(mContext, layoutResourceId, catList);

    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.catList = new ArrayList<Friends>();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    if(convertView==null){
        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }

    // object item based on the position
    Friends objectItem = data[position];

    // get the TextView and then set the text (item name) and tag (item ID) values
    TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem);
    textViewItem.setText(objectItem.getFrName());
    textViewItem.setTag(objectItem.getFrId());

    return convertView;

}
```

The Auto complete text view does not show any suggestions, is there any other way that this can be done? I will need the ID as the recipient must be a unique one.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] t_testlist = mactv.getText().toString().trim().split(",");
JSONArray jsonDocSplArray = new JSONArray();

for(int j=0; j<t_testlist.length; j++) {
    JSONObject jsonmulTest = new JSONObject();            
    jsonmulTest.put("Lists", t_testlist[j]);   
    jsonDocSplArray.put(jsonmulTest);
}

jsonData.put("DiagnosticLabTest", jsonDocSplArray);
```